# Error FS0001: The type 'string -> seq<unit>' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'

Tags: f#

I have a difficult time understanding the error messages in F#, as this is my first time using a typed functional language. Here is an example of my code:

```
let getAllFiles (directory : string) =
    Directory.GetFiles(directory)
let getFileInfo =
    getAllFiles 
    |> Seq.map (fun eachFile -> (eachFile, new FileInfo(eachFile)))
```

I received the following error message: "Error FS0001: The type 'string -> seq' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'"

What changes can I make? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are composing functions, not passing a value from one function to another, you have to use the composition operator (`>>`) instead of the pipe (`|>`):

```
open System.IO

let getAllFiles (directory : string) =
    Directory.GetFiles(directory)

let getFileInfo =
    getAllFiles 
    >> Seq.map (fun eachFile -> (eachFile, new FileInfo(eachFile)))
```

Alternatively, you can make the argument explicit and then you can use the pipe:

```
open System.IO

let getAllFiles (directory : string) =
    Directory.GetFiles(directory)

let getFileInfo directory =
    directory
    |> getAllFiles
    |> Seq.map (fun eachFile -> (eachFile, new FileInfo(eachFile)))
```

---

Update for the comment:

> If I specifically want to get the file length, how should I write it instead?

```
open System.IO

let getAllFiles directory =
    Directory.GetFiles directory 

let getFileInfos =
    getAllFiles
    >> Seq.map (fun fileName -> (fileName, FileInfo fileName))


let getFileLengths =
    getFileInfos
    >> Seq.map (fun (fileName, fileInfo) -> fileName, fileInfo.Length)
```

If you mean to get all file lengths of all the files in the directory, you could use a `getFileLengths` function like in the code above. Note that I modified the name of `getFileInfo`.

---

Update for the second comment:

> I would like to group the tuples according to the length of each file using Seq.groupBy. How may I go about doing so?

The function `removeSingletonGroups` removes all groups that contain only one value.

The function `getFilesGroupedByLength` first uses `Seq.groupBy` to create groups with the file lengths as keys, then uses `Seq.map` to remove the file length from the values, so the value of each group is only a list of filenames. Finally it uses `removeSingletonGroups` to purge all groups that contain only one file.

```
let removeSingletonGroups groupedSeq =
    groupedSeq
    |> Seq.filter (snd >> List.length >> (<>) 1)

let getFilesGroupedByLength =
    getFileLengths
    >> Seq.groupBy snd
    >> Seq.map (fun (fileLength, files) -> fileLength, files |> Seq.map fst |> List.ofSeq)
    >> removeSingletonGroups
```

---

Final(?) update:

I just saw your question regarding the duplicate file checker. I think this approach is what you were looking for:

```
open System.IO

let getFilesOfDirectory directoryPath = 
    Directory.EnumerateFiles directoryPath

let getFileLength filePath =
    (FileInfo filePath).Length

let groupFilesByLength files =
    files
    |> Seq.groupBy getFileLength

let removeSingletonGroups groupedSeq =
    groupedSeq
    |> Seq.filter (fun (_, group) -> Seq.length group > 1)

let getDuplicateFileCandidates directoryPath =
    directoryPath
    |> getFilesOfDirectory
    |> groupFilesByLength
    |> removeSingletonGroups
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, Nikon the Third. If I specifically want to get the file length, how should I write it instead?

Comment: Thanks, Nikon. I am sorry that I am asking so many rudimentary questions -- hopefully I will compensate for my lack of innate talent with persistence. :-)

I have another question: I would like to group the tuples according to the length of each file using Seq.groupBy. How may I go about doing so? My problem is that I don't quite understand the following, as found on the MSDN page:

"Seq.groupBy : ('T -> 'Key) -> seq<'T> -> seq<'Key * seq<'T>>"

Comment: @MY_G, I updated the answer again ;) I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience, Nikon. I suppose that Seq.groupBy returns a tuple with eachFileLength as the key and with a sequence of eachFiles as the value? I would like to focus only on tuples with sequences of >1 eachFiles. Do I use Seq.filter? Is there a more appropriate method?

Comment: @MY_G, now I see what you're getting at. I updated the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the directory to `getAllFiles` e.g.

```
let getFileInfo =
    getAllFiles "directory to search"
    |> Seq.map (fun eachFile -> (eachFile, new FileInfo(eachFile)))
```

usually, when you get an error like you have, where a function type `a -> ... -> b` is not compatible with type `b` then you have not provided enough arguments to the function you're using.

Comment: Thanks for you help, Lee. If I specifically want to get the file length, how should I write it instead?

Comment: @MY_G - You can use the `Length` property of the `FileInfo` instance you create e.g. `(new FileInfo(eachFile).Length)`.